# Normals doesn't show up

Tags: interface, edit-mode, normals

I have a problem on Blender:
I select an object, I switch in edit mode, and then in the "viewport overlays" menu, I click on display normals (at the bottom of the menu) but nothing appears.
The other thing is that when I want to display other types of normals ("vertex normals" and "split normals") it works.
Can someone tell me if there is something that could explain this issue ?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe face normals are fliped inside

Comment: Even if I flip them, still the same situation, I can't see them, even if I zoom et re-scale the mesh.

Comment: so it could be a bug. i dont have this problem in 2.91. somerimes changing workspaces fix this not showing up stuff